# Magento 2.3 set up an order in the admin panel that generates an order based on partial quantity & backorder on the amount not in stock

Tags: magento2.3, orders, admin-panel, backorder

In Magento 2.3 admin panel, can I set up an order that generates an order based on partial quantity & backorder on the amount not in-stock for the same item?

It should include an item that can be partially fulfilled. i.e. the order is for 5 pcs and there is just 4 in-stock

it should

1-generate an order for 4

and

2-generate a wish list or backorder for 1. This should be convertible to another order when the stock is received.